# Multiple Unique Autonomous Sessions with Python Requests

Tags: python, session, proxy, python-requests, web-crawler

I have searched through all the requests docs I can find, including requests-futures, and I can't find anything addressing this question. Wondering if I missed something or if anyone here can help answer:

**Is it possible to create and manage multiple unique/autonomous sessions with requests.Session()?**

In more detail, I'm asking if there is a way to create two sessions I could use "get" with separately (maybe via multiprocessing) that would retain their own unique set of headers, proxies, and server-assigned sticky data.

If I want Session_A to hit *someimaginarysite.com/page1.html* using specific headers and proxies, get cookied and everything else, and then hit *someimaginarysite.com/page2.html* with the same everything, I can just create one session object and do it.

But what if I want a Session_B, at the same time, to start on *page3.html* and then hit *page4.html* with *totally different headers/proxies* than Session_A, and be assigned its own cookies and whatnot? Crawl *multiple* pages consecutively with the same session, not just a single request followed by another request from a blank (new) session.

Is this as simple as saying:

```
import requests

Session_A = requests.Session()
Session_B = requests.Session()

headers_a = {A headers here}
proxies_a = {A proxies here}

headers_b = {B headers here}
proxies_b = {B proxies here}

response_a = Session_A.get('https://someimaginarysite.com/page1.html', headers=headers_a, proxies=proxies_a)
response_a = Session_A.get('https://someimaginarysite.com/page2.html', headers=headers_a, proxies=proxies_a)

# --- and on a separate thread/processor ---

response_b = Session_B.get('https://someimaginarysite.com/page3.html', headers=headers_b, proxies=proxies_b)
response_b = Session_B.get('https://someimaginarysite.com/page4.html', headers=headers_b, proxies=proxies_b)
```

Or will the above just create one session accessible by two names so the server will see the same cookies and session appearing with two ips and two sets of headers... which would seem more than a little odd.

Greatly appreciate any help with this, I've exhausted my research abilities.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is probably a better way to do this, but without more information about the pagination and exactly what you want, it is a bit hard to understand exactly what you need. The following will make 2 threads with sequential calls in each keeping the same headers and proxies. Once again, there may be a better way to approach but with the limited information it's a bit murky.

```py
import requests
import concurrent.futures

    
def session_get_same(urls, headers, proxies):
    lst = []
    with requests.Session() as s:
        for url in urls:
            lst.append(s.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies))
        
    return lst
        
def main():
    
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = [
            executor.submit(
                session_get_same,
                urls=[
                    'https://someimaginarysite.com/page1.html',
                    'https://someimaginarysite.com/page2.html'
                ],
                headers={'user-agent': 'curl/7.61.1'},
                proxies={'https': 'https://10.10.1.11:1080'}
            ),
            executor.submit(
                session_get_same,
                urls=[
                    'https://someimaginarysite.com/page3.html',
                    'https://someimaginarysite.com/page4.html'
                ],
                headers={'user-agent': 'curl/7.61.2'},
                proxies={'https': 'https://10.10.1.11:1080'}
            ),
        ]
        
        flst = []
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            flst.append(future.result())
            
        return flst
```

Not sure if this is better for the first function, mileage may vary

```py
def session_get_same(urls, headers, proxies):
    lst = []
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers.update(headers)
        s.proxies.update(proxies)
        
        for url in urls:
            lst.append(s.get(url))
        
    return lst
```